# Same picture in Xamarin.Forms splash screen and view are not same on device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Image Set in my Assets.xcassets which is called LaunchScreen
[image]

Image is set 3 times the same... Just tried if smth will change.. Normally I use just 1x
(company logo is hidden by my awful paint skill)

This imageset is used for Splashscreen.storyboard.
I use Angular on frontend, so my only content page which is visible is WebView, so to avoid black flash, before webview is navigated I want to show this image again but in this control. To do this I use

```
myControl.BackgroundImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => UIImage.FromBundle("LaunchScreen").AsPNG().AsStream());
```

In AppDelegate, but the result is that when I start the app I can see splash screen, than there is WebView's background image, but those two images are not the same size, so I can see smth like this:

[image]

After WebView loads, everything is normal again... So is problem with ImageSource? or some Align settings?

This page is added via Shell's cmd PushAsync(page, false);
So I think that animation won't be the problem

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem is somewhere in unreachable code of background image, so I've added Absolute layout and image.. now it works fine